# Search Files and Helper Apps

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal.

How do I use the helper apps with the search files module.

were to i put them or how do i apply them?

serach files: http://drupal.org/project/search_files

Answer (score 0):

I have this installed and am using the search directories part successfully. the attachment submod doesn't seem to work right. but I do have the directory part installed.

Directory Path sites/all/files/pdfs/criminal

The directory path to be searched for files. Relative pathes are kept and currently based on /var/www/html.
URI Path http://docresource.org/sites/all/files/pdfs/criminal

The URI path to retrieve files from the directory above. Usually some http:// download URL. Warning : no test access done.

my PDFs are in the folder shown above. you have to have the relative path and the urL.

you also have to have a helper app installed. I installed xpdf via YUM in Centos. 
then, you can adjust the indexing to suit the capacity of your server. I have thousands of PDFs to scan so i have to tweak it.

let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: oh, there is also a patch that I had to install. i think you had better just read thru this whole post to get an idea of what needs to be done.    https://drupal.org/node/1093268